# Display Listview item's where userid == item owner

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display `ListView` item's. Those items will be display is = to user who add it. I already got the `userid` "curentuser" and `ownerid` but the `Listview` display all item on Sql data table. My problem is the `ListView` item to display must be filtered to user who add it only . The two code is not updating but displaying only, any idea on how to display data on 'listview' that have the same value as 'userid' ? .

Here's my code CSS:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["uname"] != null ) //get userid(login user) for table display control
    {
        Class1.con.Open();
        string display = "select * from tbl_Prof where UserName='" + Session["uname"] + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(display, Class1.con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        txtcode3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["profid"].ToString();
        Class1.con.Close();
    }
    else {   }
    Class1.con.Open(); //get userid( user  login table creator) for table display control
    string display1 = "select * from tbl_Schead where userid='" + txtcode3.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(display1, Class1.con);
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    da1.Fill(ds1);
    txtcode2.Text = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["userid"].ToString();
    Class1.con.Close();
```

}

Here is the List view asp.net:

```
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" >
   <LayoutTemplate>
   <table border="0" cellpadding="1">
   <tr style="background-color:#E5E5FE">
   <th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkId" runat="server">Id</asp:LinkButton> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th> 
   <th ><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkName" runat="server">DAY</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th>
   <th><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkType" runat="server">TIME</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th>
   <th><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">COURSE</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th>
   <th><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">STUDENT COUNT</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th>
   <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
   </table>
   </LayoutTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
   <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId"><%#Eval("sid") %></asp:Label>
   </td>
   <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName"><%#Eval("sday") %></asp:Label>
   </td>
   <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblType"><%#Eval("stime") %>
   </asp:Label></td>
   <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"><%#Eval("scourse") %>
   </asp:Label></td>
   <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2"><%#Eval("sstudcount") %>
   </asp:Label></td>
   <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3"><%#Eval("userid") %>
   </asp:Label></td>
   <th>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="VIEW" CommandName="VIEW" CommandArgument= '<%#Eval("userid")%>'/>
   <td></td>
   </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Don´t paste images of code, instead post the code into your question directly. Makes it much easier for further readers that may have the same question to fint your solution.

Comment: Yes it is , I just want to compare 2 value to display content on list view that have the same value on data table.

Answer (score 0):

On "SQL DATASOURCE" select configure,select table and click "WHERE" ,select "Column" note: what table you want to compare , "Operator" is '=' , "Source" is "Control" select 'TextBox1' and hit "ADD" then 'Ok','Ok',Finish .